# if clause in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i need help for a query in Oracle SQL. Here is a table example:

```
time                      var
'2015.07.08 01:00:01'     0.1
'2015.07.08 01:00:02'     0.15
'2015.07.08 01:00:03'     0.22
'2015.07.08 01:00:04'     0.13
'2015.07.08 01:00:05'     0
'2015.07.08 01:00:06'     0.1
'2015.07.08 01:00:07'     0.02
'2015.07.08 01:00:08'     0
'2015.07.08 01:00:20'     0.1
```

Now i need all time differences from object x+1 and x if *var* equal 0. For this example i want to see this output in seconds:

```
1   # '2015.07.08 01:00:06' - '2015.07.08 01:00:05'
12  # '2015.07.08 01:00:20' - '2015.07.08 01:00:08'
```

How is the statement for: *if var==0  calculate time(row+1) - time(row)*.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Ordered by what logic? Ordered by `time` or by `var`?

Answer (score 1):

Use LAG to look into the previous record:

```
select (time - time_before) * 24 * 60 * 60
from
(
  select
    time, 
    var, 
    lag(var) over (order by time) as var_before,
    lag(time) over (order by time) as time_before
  from mytable
)
where var_before = 0
order by time;
```

Oops, that was overly complicated. Use LEAD to look into the next record instead :-)

```
select (lead(time) over (order by time) - time) * 24 * 60 * 60
from mytable
where var = 0
order by time;
```

The first query is a bit more precise, though. If the last record contains 0, then this will not be considered by query 1, because there is no later record. The second query, however, will return NULL, because LEAD(time) results in NULL when there is no following record. It's up to you to decide whether this bothers you or not.